# SQL splitting up a table into two tables based on ID

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Table that has an ID column and an interaction column.
I want to  create two new SQL tables that has each ID but i want to split up the interactions in half. So both new tables would have every ID in the old table. For example for ID 1 interaction 10231232202 would go to one table and interaction 890890834939 would go to the other table. I ignore instances that have less than 10 interactions.
How exactly can I do this?

```
╔════╦═══════════════╗
║ ID ║  Interaction  ║
╠════╬═══════════════╣
║  1 ║ 10231232202   ║ 
║  1 ║ 890890834939  ║ 
║  3 ║ 329489023849  ║
║  5 ║ 345453202389  ║
║  3 ║ 012340382448  ║ 
╚════╩═══════════════╝
```

Expected result

new table 1

```
╔════╦═══════════════╗
║ ID ║  Interaction  ║
╠════╬═══════════════╣
║  1 ║ 10231232202   ║
║  5 ║ 345453202389  ║ 
║  1 ║ 890890834939  ║ 
╚════╩═══════════════╝
```

new table 2

```
╔════╦═══════════════╗
║ ID ║  Interaction  ║
╠════╬═══════════════╣
║  3 ║ 329489023849  ║  
║  3 ║ 012340382448  ║ 
╚════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Added expected result.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: im actually using sparksql lol

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a column with the split as:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by interaction) % 2 as which_file
from t;
```

Note that this uses `%` for the modulo operator.  In some databases, this is spelled `mod()` or `mod` (as an infix operator).

Putting the data into separate tables requires additional work -- depending on the database.